# Biopython issue in finding motifs in strings and deleting target sequence

Tags: python, biopython

Hi I have a large FASTA file which looks like this

```
>EMBOSS_001
GTCATCACAGTTTTCCCCGCCCTGTATATGGCTAATAGGCCCTCGCAATCTCCGATAAAT
>EMBOSS_002
CTGATGCTAGTCCCGTGTCCCAAACACTTCCGCAGAAGATCGCCCCGGGGGGCGTGTACC
>EMBOSS_003
CGCGCATGGACTCCATCCGTGATCTTTTGAGGCCATGAGTCCAAGTTTACCTCGGATATA
>EMBOSS_004
CGACCCGCCATTCTCCATCGTAACTTAGTCACGACGACAGTCAGCTTGTTCGTTCGTTAT
```

I would like to find all the sequences which have a specific motif and eliminate them
For example if the motif is TTTCCC, the expected output should be:

```
>EMBOSS_002 CTGATGCTAGTCCCGTGTCCCAAACACTTCCGCAGAAGATCGCCCCGGGGGGCGTGTACC
>EMBOSS_003 CGCGCATGGACTCCATCCGTGATCTTTTGAGGCCATGAGTCCAAGTTTACCTCGGATATA
>EMBOSS_004 CGACCCGCCATTCTCCATCGTAACTTAGTCACGACGACAGTCAGCTTGTTCGTTCGTTAT
```

I wrote a code with Biopython:

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq
import Bio.motifs as motifs
from Bio import SeqIO

instances = [Seq("TTTCCC")]
m = motifs.create(instances)

reads = list(SeqIO.parse("/Users/EMBOSS-6.6.0/emboss/genome.fa", "fasta"))

for i in range(len(reads)):
    for pos, seq in m.instances.search(reads[i].seq):
        print("%i %s" % (pos, seq))
```

However it returns me only the info of the position of the start of the motifs, 11 TTTCCC
I would like to return the info of also the sequence where it was found:
EMBOSS_001 11 TTTCCC
In addition, I would like the code to eliminate that sequence where the motif was found.

In addition, I am not able to delete the string where the motif was found and write it to output

```
for i in range(len(reads)):
    for pos, seq in m.instances.search(reads[i].seq):
        print(" %s %i %s" % (reads[i - 0][1:], pos, seq))
        del reads[i - 0:i]
        SeqIO.write(reads, "/Users/EMBOSS-6.6.0/emboss/results6.fa", "fasta")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test this locally but I will explain with some code on how you can go about solving this problem.

If the file structure is as you mentioned then one of the points you can derive is that where instances are checked they happen on an even line (say `n`) and what sequence they represent is simply `n-1`. So in order for you to output in this format `EMBOSS_001 11 TTTCCC` - the simplest of way is to use the index `i` as counter and determine the sequence.

For example: `reads[i-1]` would give you the sequence `>EMBOSS_001` for the FASTA `GTCATCACAGTTTTCCCCGCCCTGTATATGGCTAATAGGCCCTCGCAATCTCCGATAAAT` . To remove the `>`, set it to `reads[i-1][1:]`.

To eliminate the seq when motif `TTTCCC` is found, there are many ways to do this. The simplest would be to use the `del` method for python list-objects. This will simply remove the sequence and the element in which the motif occurs.

This can be done easily and this is how the change would look in your code

```
for pos, seq in m.instances.search(reads[i].seq):
        print(" %s %i %s" % (reads[i-1][1:],pos, seq))#should print in format EMBOSS_001 11 TTTCCC
        del reads[i-1:i]
```

This should hopefully solve it. Let me know if you encounter any errors.

**Edit:**
My initial write intention should have looked like this - have also added a break statement to see if it solves the problem.

```
for i in range(len(reads)):
    for pos, seq in m.instances.search(reads[i].seq):
        print(" %s %i %s" % (reads[i - 0][1:], pos, seq))
        del reads[i - 0:i]
        break 
SeqIO.write(reads, "/Users/EMBOSS-6.6.0/emboss/results6.fa", "fasta")
```

Where once the motifs were found it would eliminate that sequence. This means that only the strings without the motifs should now be written to `SeqIO.write()` method.

Comment: hi, thanks, it kind of worked but I had to change to i-0 instead then i-1 because it was pointing to the ID of following sequence I think.

Comment: by the way, if I want to write to a new file the output do I need to use seqIO.write?

Comment: yeah I used seqIO.write to write a fasta file after deleting the sequence where the motif was found as you said but the sequence was not deleted

Comment: yeah I-1 was pointing to the last sequence of the file instead

Comment: @PaoloLorenzini I think you can use `seqIO.write` to write the output. If the sequence is appearing in the write file then this maybe due to that you maybe writing the file before the sequence is deleted. Can you ask another question on how you are writting this and @ me here?

Comment: do you mean should I open another post and ask another question from the beginning?

Comment: Sure if the topic is within the title then edit and let me know

Comment: isntead of writing `SeqIO.write(reads, "/Users/EMBOSS-6.6.0/emboss/results6.fa", "fasta")` can you pass the first parameter as `reads[i]` to refer to it. Writing with all reads seams like it applies the whole reads list contents to the file

Comment: I see, by doing that now I get an output where all the sequences where the motif was not  there were deleted , so basically I get an output where there is only the sequence which was deleted, where the motif was found

Comment: Alternatively, assuming the delete happens with ` del reads[i-1:i]`  - you can simply have a write statement outside of the nested for loop and then write them that way. This way the `seq` were motif was found will have been deleted and you will only write whatever is left in the array. Place this `        SeqIO.write(reads, "/Users/EMBOSS-6.6.0/emboss/results6.fa", "fasta")` outside the loops

Comment: apparently if I do that only the last sequence of the list will be written in the output

Comment: That's weird.. I will edit an explanation to my answer in a min

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225046/discussion-between-azycrw4282-and-paolo-lorenzini).

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(reads)):
    for pos, seq in m.instances.search(reads[i].seq):
        seq_rem = str(" %s %i %s" % (reads[i - 0][1:], pos, seq))
        reads_dict = SeqIO.to_dict(reads)
        seq_rem = seq_rem.splitlines()[0][5:]
del reads_dict[seq_rem]
SeqIO.write(reads_dict.values(), "/Users/EMBOSS-6.6.0/emboss/results10.fa", "fasta")
```

I have managed to come up with something like this which works